# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My SQL Server `WHERE` condition is below.

```
WHERE ([Orders].ORTakenDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-08-13 00:00:00', 105) 
AND [Orders].ORTakenDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-09-29 00:00:00', 105))
```

the datatype is datetime2, when I execute this gives me error:

**ERROR**

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using format 105 for this?  Use the right format for YYYY-MM-DD format, 121:

```
        WHERE ([Orders].ORTakenDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-08-13 00:00:00', 121) AND
               [Orders].ORTakenDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-09-29 00:00:00', 121))
```

The formats are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

EDIT:

SQL Server generally recognizes date constants in the format YYYY-MM-DD, so you should be able to simplify this to:

```
        WHERE ([Orders].ORTakenDate >= '2014-08-13' AND
               [Orders].ORTakenDate <= '2014-09-29'
              )
```

(There is one case with an international format where the date constant is not interpreted correctly.)

Comment: but when i am using this query from c# code behind it gives me error.

Comment: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GetAllOrdersDetailsByDate'. A member of the type, 'SSMA_TimeStamp1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Comment: @Tashi . . . That would not seem to be related to the use of `convert()` in a `where` clause.  Perhaps you should ask another question.

Comment: oops, its my problem i have remove timestamp1 and its works fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

in 105 format  date `'2014-09-29 00:00:00'` considers 29 as month which is out of range.

So either you should re-arrange your strings or use different format

Comment: my database entry is 2014-08-13 00:00:00 like this

Answer (score 0):

```
in SQL it might be 

WHERE ([Orders].ORTakenDate >= cast('2014-08-13 00:00:00' as datetime) 
                  AND [Orders].ORTakenDate <= cast('2014-09-29 00:00:00' as datetime)

------------------------OR--------------------------------------------------

WHERE ([Orders].ORTakenDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '13-08-2014 00:00:00', 105) 
                  AND [Orders].ORTakenDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '29-09-2014 00:00:00', 105))
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `105` then date should be in `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss` formate..

so use like this

```
WHERE ([Orders].ORTakenDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '13-08-2014 00:00:00', 105) 
AND [Orders].ORTakenDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '29-09-2014 00:00:00', 105))
```

**Update :**

If you are passing date from C# then first convert value in   `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss` formate..

Comment: SELECT Orders.*,[Order Details].*
 
 FROM         dbo.Orders INNER JOIN
                      dbo.[Sales Ledger Transactions] ON dbo.Orders.ORSTMN = dbo.[Sales Ledger Transactions].STMN INNER JOIN
                      dbo.[Order Details] ON dbo.[Order Details].ODORMN = dbo.Orders.ORMN
                      WHERE ([Orders].ORTakenDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '13-08-2014 00:00:00', 105) 
                      AND [Orders].ORTakenDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '29-09-2014 00:00:00', 105))
     ORDER BY dbo.[Order Details].ODMN DESC

Comment: the error: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GetAllOrdersDetailsByDate_Result'. A member of the type, 'SSMA_TimeStamp1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.